# Combine 65000 small xml files in blobs storage and copy them into data lake as big CSV files

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-data-lake, azure-queues, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I have around 65000 small xml files (around 1 to 3 kb per file) per hour in Azure blob storage. Its telemetry data and will be there in blob each hour. I want to combine them all and create big xml files(hourly one file or so) and convert that into big csv file.Then I want to copy it into in azure data lake store, so that I can further do analysis on that using U-SQL scripts. Please tell me what is the correct way to do this.

Right now we are using azure batch service which does this by keeping all file names in Azure table storage and each task in batch service will read data from table storage and update it once complete.

I think we can do better than this using web job sdk and Azure Service bus - topics and subscription. For each hour we can consider one topic and one subscriber.

Let me know that my thinking is correct or we can do this with some better technique.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you could directly combine and convert the xml files to csv in the web job(You data is not very large). After the operation completely, you could upload the converted file to the data lake store.

But if you use this way, you couldn't keep the data in real time upload to the data lake store.

You could use azure web job [timer trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger)(run the convert code each hour) to help you to combine and convert the data.

If you want to keep the data in real time, I suggest you could consider using webjob(using [blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to)) to read the data to service bus firstly, then you could use stream analysis to convert the data to csv in data store lake.

Comment: Does blob trigger will handle those many new jobs? around 20 new blobs per second?

Comment: Now,the blob trigger couldn't be fired immediately. If you want to fired immediately and large you need use  [Azure Service Bus Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus).

Comment: If it is firing after some time, I am ok. But I am more concern about how Azure function will handle this load. As per my knowledge each azure function all will start new VM and it will run our code on that VM. So in my case - does it starts 65000 VMs per hours? Also there is not too much work for each VM as I just want to convert small xml to csv and upload it to data lake store. Does it make sense? I think I do not have much knowledge of how Azure Function works? Please help me to understand this.

Comment: As far as I know, this will according to which azure function hosting plans you have used. Firstly, azure function could async run your method. So it will not starts 65000VMs. If you use Consumption plan, it will auto scale the vm to make your method run well. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).